# Only one thread have access to a certain part of code?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a project which requires logging in my router from time to time and make some changes. In eclipse I have a separate project which deals with all the things I need changed and I have that in the build path of my main project which is a multi threaded project. My problem is that sometimes two threads try to access the router which messes things up. Is there anything I can do that only one thread can access a certan part of my code.

This is the related code for the main multithreaded application

```
if (totalLogins > 10)
{
  IpManager.rebootRouter();
  Thread.sleep(4000);
  totalLogins = 0;
  composedMessagesWithThisIP = 0;
}
```

And in the other project this is what I have

```
public synchronized static void rebootRouter()
{
  try
  {
    //code related to restart modem
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {

  }
}
```

So what I have done is made the method synchronized but I believe from time to time more than one thread access the "rebootRouter" method. Which causes problems in my main application.

What is the best way and most effective way to make IpManager.rebootRouter() be executed by one thread only?

Regards!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question:  do you want to ensure that only one thread executes `rebootRouter()` *at any given time*?  Or do you want to make sure that only one unique thread *ever* accesses `rebootRouter()`, and no other threads are allowed to, even if no threads are currently executing it?

Comment: @Turix I want one thread to execute it at any given time. It does not matter if a different thread accesses it.

Comment: Just by looking at your code, it seems to me that only one thread will run the code inside rebootRouter() at any given time, coz you are synchronizing a static method already (unless you have multiple copy of that class due to multiple classloader but I believe it is a rare situation).  Therefore it is probably NOT because of concurrent access messing up your system

Comment: Are you synchronizing the right portion of code ?
In your first code snippet, you wait 4 secs after the reboot. Why ?
Do you wait for the end of the reboot process in your sync'block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`synchronized` guarantees that only one thread can enter the block at a time, but AFAIR the same thread can enter the block multiple times (so threads don't deadlock against themselves), and if a thread is blocked because another thread is in there then it may run immediately after the first thread leaves the synchronized block.

First I'd throw logging at the entry and exit points of the routine.
I'd check to see that you don't have any recursion going on, and make sure that the calls really are running at the same time.  Also, remember if there's any asynchronous work or callbacks the synchronized block may be exited.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Semaphore** from `java.util.concurrent package`, to **restrict** the Number of thread accessing the object.

**Example:**

Here in this code snippet, only 1 thread can access the object at a time.

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);  

s.acquire();

synchronized(this){

// Your modem work

}

s.release();
```

Comment: The semaphore here is neither sufficient nor necessary. You could just as well only use a synchronized block. (The call to `s.release()` should be in a `finally` block, too.)

Comment: Semaphore is a clean way of handling the above problem, moreover i have given just how Semaphore looks and what it needs to have.. I am not showing the entire code, else i would have taken proper care of try catch and finally blocks over here. But thanks for pointing it out... that will be helpful to the person who asked this question

Comment: So why do you mix semaphores and synchronized blocks, then? One is enough (and synchronized blocks are simpler, which is better).

Comment: What do you mean "won't restrict the number of threads"? Only one thread can execute a synchronized block for a given object at a time.

Comment: Sorry... i didnt mean to say that.... but semaphores can be used to send signals between threads to avoid missed signals, or to guard a critical section like you would with a lock

Answer (score 0):

`So what I have done is made the method synchronized but I believe from time to time more than one thread access the "rebootRouter" method.`

As you have marked this method as `synchronized` it guarantees that more than one thread can not execute this method simultaneously .  It may be code in side `// Your modem work` has some `unsynchronized`  stuff that may cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that sometimes two threads try to access the router which messes things up. Is there anything I can do that only one thread can access a certan part of my code.

Define "messes things up". Since `rebootRouter` is synchronized, only one thread can run that method at any given time. But if a thread, call it thread A, tries to invoke it while another thread (thread B) runs it, thread A will block until B returns from `rebootRouter`, and A will then directly call `rebootRouter` itself. If this is the behavior you want, your problems are elsewhere (`synchronized` is not broken, or someone would've noticed).

If you want thread A in the example above to not invoke `rebootRouter` if it is called by another thread when in the example above, you can use [`Lock.tryLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28%29):

```
private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public static void rebootRouter() {
  if (!lock.tryLock()) return;
  try {
    //code related to restart modem
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Note: Empty catch blocks considered bad style
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

If your needs are more specific, you probably need to rephrase your question.